# Coq: rewriting under if-then-else

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, rewriting

I sometimes need to apply a simplification in a branch of an if-then-else without destructing the discriminee.

```
From Coq Require Import Setoid.

Lemma true_and :
  forall P, True /\ P <-> P.
Proof.
  firstorder.
Qed.

Goal (forall (b:bool) P Q, if b then True /\ P else Q).
  intros.
  Fail rewrite (true_and P).
Abort.
```

In this example `rewrite` fails (`setoid_rewrite` too), suggesting to register the following

- `"subrelation eq (Basics.flip Basics.impl)"`: seems fair to me
- `"subrelation iff eq"`: no way!

Why is the rewriting engine so demanding?

Answer (score 1):

I think the rewriting strategies are failing because what you want is not a rewriting, it's a reduction (`True /\ P` is not technically equal to `P`). If you want to maintain the `if then else` statement, I'll suggest the following solution (yet a bit unsatisfactory):

In a `Tactics.v` file, add the following lemma and ltacs :

```
Lemma if_then_else_rewrite:
  forall (b: bool) (T1 T2 E1 E2 : Prop),
    (T1 -> T2) ->
    (E1 -> E2) ->
    (if b then T1 else E1) ->
    (if b then T2 else E2).
Proof.
  destruct b; auto.
Qed.

Ltac ite_app1 Th :=
  match goal with
  | H:_ |- if ?b then ?T2 else ?E =>
    eapply if_then_else_rewrite with (E1 := E) (E2 := E);
    [eapply Th | eauto |]
   end.


Ltac ite_app2 Th :=
  match goal with
  | H:_ |- if ?b then ?T else ?E2 =>
    eapply if_then_else_rewrite with (T1 := T) (T2 := T);
    [eauto | eapply Th |]
   end.
```

Then, when you have a goal with a top-level `if then else`, you can apply a theorem `Th` to either the left or right side with `ite_app1 Th` or `ite_app2 Th`. For example, you goal would be :

```
Goal (forall (b:bool) P Q, if b then (True /\ P) else Q).
  intros.
  ite_app1 true_and. (* -> if b then P else Q *)
```

You'll probably need to fine-tune the ltacs to your needs (apply in the context vs in the goal, etc.), but that's a first solution. Maybe someone can bring more ltac dark magic to solve this in a more general way.

Comment: Thanks! Following your suggestion I came up with the following tactic which still take advantage of the rewriting engine (efficient at selecting sub-terms except under if-then-else...): `Ltac ite_rewrite Hr :=
  rewrite Hr
  || match goal with
    | |- context [ if _ then _ else _ ] =>
      rewrite if_then_else_rewrite;
      [ | ite_rewrite Hr; reflexivity
        | ite_rewrite Hr; reflexivity ]
    | _ => idtac
    end.` (after changing implications with equivalences in `if_then_else_rewrite`)

Comment: Yeah that is better ! You may find it useful at some point that the tactic create new goals that are not solved immediately (i.e. where `reflexivity` is not enough), so you can do your rewrites and have still complex proofs for the rewrite without expliciting them before (forward reasoning tend to be more fragile to definition/lemma changes).